# Discrete Model Finding Stability

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, bifurcation

For the discrete model $$x_{t+1} = (\lambda +1)x_t +x_t^3$$

Draw a bifurcation diagram (expressing the equilibrium vs $\lambda$ for values of $\lambda$ near zero.

I have the bifurcation diagram. It has a sideways parabola shape, and if $\lambda = 0$ by a phase line analysis I have that it is semi stable. I am having trouble determining the stability of the rest of the bifurcation diagram